# Mac has become insanely slow : Processes SystemUIServer, UserEventAgent and loginwindow using a lot of memory

Tags: macos, mac, memory, performance

I have been using my Mac for for many months without any problem. But recently all of a sudden the Mac became insanely slow.

I opened Activity Manager to see what was happening. For three processes SystemUIServer,  UserEventAgent and loginwindow, the memory gradually increases and reaches upto 2 GB for each process. This completely hangs up my Mac.

I tried the following : 
 1. Restart Mac
 2. Restart Mac in safe mode
 3. Manually kill the processes
 4. Remove Date and Time from Menu bar(this was supposed to be the problem for the SysteUIServer process's memory according to many users)
 5. Removed the externally connected keyboard and mouse(some had suggested this for UserEventAgent's memory)

No luck with any of those.
The moment I log in, the memory spikes up.

Any idea what the hell is happening? Please help.